# Setup devise with custom registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm working on a rails site using devise, where we do not want user sign ups just yet. User authentication is so we can login to access restricted parts of the site and add/edit things as we see fit. So for now, I created the following controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new

  end
end
```

And setup my routes in this fashion:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registration => "users/registration" }
```

However, when I run rake routes, I still see a returned value for the create action on the registration controller. Any ideas on how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `:registrations` instead of `:registration`. Also, it seems like your custom controller class should be defined via:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

Comment: Whoops. Well i fixed the name on the inheritance, and corrected the routes file. (This is why I shouldnt code at 1am ;) ). Though it still looks like I have those routes kicking around. Here's what I see in terms of the registration: http://pastie.org/2491033

Comment: So I tried what's suggested here: http://sikachu.com/2010/12/my-devise-custom-routes/ Using the skip option, and specified my own. It seems to work. I still get the first list of responses from rake routes for devise/registrations, but doing a POST to /users/sign_up returned route not found, so it seems to be working as expected. I had to change Users:: to Devise:: as well.